# Strange orientation behaviour of MovieViewController

Tags: ios, swift, orientation, mpmoviewcontroller

So in my app there is an `MPMoviePlayerViewController` which allows the user to view a video. They are able to watch the video in the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` in any orientation and once they are finished and hit "done" they return to the previous view controller but in portrait only. The problem is that when the 'Done' button is pressed, the View Controller briefly flashes up in landscape before returning to portrait like it should. This is what it looks like when running: http://1drv.ms/1RSqUUD

My code is attached:

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class VideoViewController: UIViewController {

var movieViewController : MPMoviePlayerViewController?
var movieplayer : MPMoviePlayerController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    var url = NSURL(string: "http://jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v")!
    movieViewController = MPMoviePlayerViewController(contentURL: url)
}



override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
    UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
}

@IBAction func WatchPressed(sender: AnyObject)
{
    self.presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated(movieViewController)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "Rotated", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
}


func Rotated()
{
    if UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation)
    {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.rawValue == 4 ||  UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.rawValue == 3
        {
            movieViewController!.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height)

        }
    }
    else if UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation)
    {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.rawValue == 1 || UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.rawValue == 2
        {
            movieViewController!.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height)

            let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
            UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
        }
```

**EDIT**

When using this code: (as was suggested below) 
http://txt.do/nt1s
The user is thrown out of the movie player when they rotate to landscape and they still briefly see the previous view controller in landscape before it rotates to portrait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it this way:

First of all In your `viewDidLoad` add this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    //This observer will call doneButtonClick method when done button is pressed.
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "doneButtonClick:", name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification, object: nil)

    var url = NSURL(string: "http://jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v")!
    movieViewController = MPMoviePlayerViewController(contentURL: url)
}
```

After that add this method:

```
func doneButtonClick(sender:NSNotification?){
    let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
    UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
}
```

Which will forcibly change your orientation to portrait.

It is working fine.

Comment: I have just tried it but whenever I try and watch the video in landscape the user is removed from the video player and shown the view controller in landscape before rotating to portrait... @Dharmesh_Khani

Comment: Should I replace my function called "rotated" with your function? My code is here: http://txt.do/nt1s

Comment: Hi Again. I am still using this method but have one issue. When the video is paused, the 'Done' button does nothing. Can you see why? Thanks

Comment: Hi Dharmesh did you solve the issue with the done button now working properly? Thnks

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30939570/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-done-button-doesnt-work-properly

Comment: I asked that question :P Could you sort it?

Comment: ahh sorry I didn't notice it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81117/discussion-between-dharmesh-kheni-and-dwinnbrown).