# Swift - Can't Dismiss MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: xcode, swift, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a video which opens in an `MPMoviePlayerController` in my app. It all works great except for the `Done` button which should close the player. The first time that the video is played the `Done` button works great. But if you pause it when you are watching it, then hit `Done` the second time you try to play the video, the `Done` button doesn't work. I have made a screen recording here to make it a bit simpler to understand:
http://1drv.ms/1Jcdodc

Can anyone help?

This is my code that I am using:

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class MainContent: UIViewController {

//Movie Player variables
    var movieViewController : MPMoviePlayerViewController?
    var movieplayer : MPMoviePlayerController!


override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Video Player setup
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "doneButtonClick:", name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification, object: nil)

        var url = NSURL(string: "http://jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v")!
        movieViewController = MPMoviePlayerViewController(contentURL: url)

}



func doneButtonClick(sender:NSNotification?){
    let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
    UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
    }

        //when watch button is pressed, present the movie player
    @IBAction func watchPressed(sender: AnyObject)
    {self.presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated(movieViewController)}

 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this issue, I added the `myMoviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.stop()` to the 'doneButtonClick' function. I then added the `myMoviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.play()` again to the

```
@IBAction func watchPressed(sender: AnyObject)
    {self.presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated(movieViewController)}

 }
```

So all in all a simple fix! Code is below:

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class MainContent: UIViewController {

//Movie Player variables
    var movieViewController : MPMoviePlayerViewController?
    var movieplayer : MPMoviePlayerController!


override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Video Player setup
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "doneButtonClick:", name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification, object: nil)

        var url = NSURL(string: "http://jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v")!
        movieViewController = MPMoviePlayerViewController(contentURL: url)

}

 func doneButtonClick(sender:NSNotification?){
    let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
    UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
    movieViewController?.moviePlayer.stop()
  }

    @IBAction func watchPressed(sender: AnyObject){
        self.presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated(movieViewController)
        movieViewController?.moviePlayer.play()
    }
}
```