# Reset MPMoviePlayerViewController Playback

Tags: ios, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a video in my application which plays within a `MPMoviePlayerViewController`. I want to know if it is possible to reset the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` when a button is pressed. At the moment, if the user taps `Done` whilst the video is playing and then tries to watch the video again it continues where they left off. This is causing a few problems with some of my other code and I would like it to start from the beginning. Is this possible?

---

I would like the video to reset itself when the `Done` button is pressed, so that it is ready for next time.

I have a function and would like to add the reset of the video in here.

```
func doneButtonClick(sender:NSNotification?) {
    let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
    UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
}
```

Comment: Have you tried just changing the playback time to the start of the video with `[player setCurrentPlaybackTime:0];`?

Comment: @timgcarlson I did think about that but I would like to try and reset the entire player as it is causing some other issues that I can't solve and thought it might be a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30939570/swift-cant-dismiss-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell your video to `stop`. Then call `play` when you want to play the video again. This will initiate playback from the beginning of the video.

```
myMoviePlayerController.stop()
```

[**MPMediaPlayback Protocol Reference**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MPMediaPlayback/stop)

Comment: Thanks. Will give that a go and let you know if it works and sove the other issue posted above :)

Comment: I have now successfully implemented the stop function but now, when I try to watch the video a second time, it won't work?

Comment: I have sorted it all out. Added the .stop function for the done button click and then added the .play function to the button which presents the video.